# What is this technique in linux kernel called?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, watchdog

Hi i have a watchdog linux driver as below:

```
struct omap_wdt_dev { 
    struct watchdog_device wdev;
    struct device *dev;
    void __iomem *base_addr;
    uint32_t ttgr_pattern;  
};
static int omap_wdt_start(struct watchdog_device *wdev)
{
    struct omap_wdt_dev *omap_wdev = watchdog_get_drvdata(wdev);
    /*...*/
    omap_wdt_reload(omap_wdev);
    return 0;
}
static int omap_wdt_plf_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct omap_wdt_dev *omap_wdev;
    omap_wdev = kzalloc(sizeof(*omap_wdev), GFP_KERNEL);
    watchdog_set_drvdata(wdev, (void *)omap_wdev);
    /*...*/
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, they have created a struct `omap_wdt_dev` which have a `watchdog_device`inside it. Then in probe function `omap_wdt_plf_probe`, they use a void pointer inside `watchdog_device` to point to "wdev" by the function:`watchdog_set_drvdata(wdev, (void *)omap_wdev)`. Then in function `omap_wdt_start` which have input parameter is a `watchdog_device`, they get the `omap_wdt_dev` from `watchdog_device` to use `omap_wdt_dev`. 
I see this technical, use a void pointer to contain the data of a struct, is used frequently in linux kernel, but i do not know the name of this technique.

Can you explain me more about it and show me some another technique which is used in linux kernel ?

Comment: its called an "opaque pointer"

Comment: @Basile: it seems your draft report is a solution for everything today. :)

Comment: @Groo: that report is not a solution (but explains that there is [no silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)). A proposal and some incomplete tool